# Flex wrap around image

Tags: css, vue.js, flexbox, positioning

I'm trying to position the second text element in this picture but I can't seem to be able to do it.
[image: Example card]

The current arrangement is like this:

```css
.crew-member-card {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #292929;
  padding-top: 15px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.name-and-profile-picture {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.pfp {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.userNames {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.pronouns-position {
  color: #c7c7c7;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.pronouns-position>* {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="crew-member-card">
  <div class="name-and-profile-picture">
    <p><img :src="getProfilePicture(user)" class="pfp"></p>
    <h3 class="userNames">{{ user.FirstName }} {{ user.LastName }}</h3>
    <div class="pronouns-position">
      <p class="pronouns" v-if="user.memberInfo.pronouns != 'Unset'">
        <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-solid fa-user" /> {{ user.memberInfo.pronouns.toLowerCase() }}</p>
      <p class="division-dot" v-if="user.memberInfo.pronouns != 'Unset'"> • </p>
      <p class="position">{{ user.memberInfo.position.toLowerCase() }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It results in the text going all the way under the image, rather than under the text and beside the image

Comment: _"It results in the text going all the way under the image"_ - these _unreplaced_ template placeholders are too wide to fit next to the image, but if I replace them with a shorter first and last name, it "fits". Please try and rather give an example using actual HTML code when asking a styling question like this, and not templating code that we are missing the actual setup for.

Comment: Yeah honestly coming back to this post after a while I can't even tell what I was triyng to ask. I did end up figuring out what I wanted though

Answer (score 1):

Grid is by far the best way to arrange this sort of layout. To get you started here's a few resources:

- CSS tricks - [a complete guide to grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)
- Kevin Powell - [Learn CSS the easy way](https://youtu.be/rg7Fvvl3taU)
- Kevin Powell - [Get started with grid without being overwhelmed](https://youtu.be/8QSqwbSztnA)
- W3Schools - [Grid Module](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp)
- Learn CSS Grid - [does what it says](https://learncssgrid.com/)
- MDN - [Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid)

Your layout using grid can be seen below. I've annotated the pertinent bits:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #191919;
}

.crew-member-card {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #292929;
  padding-top: 15px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.name-and-profile-picture {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; /* have 2 columns and make them the same width. This will mean the pronouns section will automatically fall on to the next row down*/
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center; /* added this */
  /*flex-wrap: wrap; removed this */
}

.pfp {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.userNames {
  color: #E6E6E6;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.pronouns-position {
  color: #c7c7c7;
  grid-column: span 2; /* this spans 2 columns to make it full width */
  display: flex; /* make the child elements appear side by side */
  justify-content: center; /* and in the center */
}

.pronouns-position>* {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<div class="crew-member-card">
  <div class="name-and-profile-picture">
    <p><img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" class="pfp"></p>
    <h3 class="userNames">Felix Cat</h3>
    <div class="pronouns-position">
      <p class="pronouns" v-if="user.memberInfo.pronouns != 'Unset'">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i> pronouns
      </p>
      <p class="division-dot" v-if="user.memberInfo.pronouns != 'Unset'"> • </p>
      <p class="position">Position</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```